# Write text content to a new window (or change the type of content from html to text)?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, opera

How to prepare a text content to be readily saved by the user?

```
document.write("this text must be saved")
```

almost does the work, but the content of the page is perceived by the browsers as html, and will be saved as `html`. Can I change it to `text/plain`?

I know I can generate it with "data:" uri, but then there is no way to specify the default file name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to do

```
document.open('text/plain');
document.write('Save me');
```

? Though I don't really understand how this suggests a file name when one tries to save. You're charting new (and very under-specified) territory here it seems.

Comment: Yes buddy!! That is it. It works with Firefox at least. I can use it with history.pushState("","", "newTitle.csv"); to change the title right before sending your code. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, I'm not 100% sure suggesting a file name with history.pushState() is *supposed to* work ;) but at least you can enjoy having found a solution while it lasts..

Comment: text/plain with document.open doesn't seem to be supported by Safari or Chrome.

Comment: It is specified in HTML5 so presumably they will want to support it at some point: http://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dynamic-markup-insertion.html#dom-document-open - but I can see why it's not exactly considered an important detail :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this header to the response: `Content-Type: text/plain`

Comment: I actually need a solution purely on client side, using javascript. Using document.write("<html><head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/plain'/> </head> <body> some text </body></html>") does not give the desired result. Or I missed something?

Comment: By the time it goes to document.write, the browser has already figured out the mime type either by looking at the header or by doing mime sniffing or reverting to default.

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This will cause the file download dialog to show. The page won't be rendered as text.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do it on client side only? Thanks.

Comment: nope i dont think so, you have to set headers from server and send data from there, this will cause a tab to open and the download window will appear, and then tab will be closed automatically.